# Alternative styling for get and set methods

Tags: java, styles

We are all familiar with Java's "getter & setter" methods. They are a great way to create data encapsulation; ensuring that any private fields outside of a classes code can only be accessed through these specific methods. These methods may then include checks, overhead, synchronization etc.

```
public class Person(){
    private String name;
    private int birthYear;

    // traditional getter/setter syntax
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public int getBirthYear(){ return birthYear; }
    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear){ this.birthYear = birthYear; }

    // proposed overloading getter/setter syntax
    public String name(){ return name; }
    public int birthYear(){ return birthYear; }
    public void name(String name){ this.name = name; }
    public void birthYear(int birthYear){ this.birthYear = birthYear; }

}
```

My question is if there is anything wrong with using method overloading to have the "proposed" syntax above for getter/setters? To me it seems more readable and intuitive:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name("Bob");
System.out.println(p.name());
```

The big disadvantage I can think of is that everybody is so used to the get/set syntax that it'll make things less readable. Anyway, it's not a major issue, I don't mind using getters/setters but I've just thought of this alternative way that looks prettier to me and wanted to know what other people think?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Although "get" and "set" are merely a convention - they're absolutely necessary for Java beans to work correctly with reflection.

You can find out more be reading about [BeanINfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/beaninfo.html) or about [class Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)

Comment: Although I know about Java Beans and Introspection, I haven't really applied them much yet. Still, I'm now convinced it would be a bad idea to deviate from the get/set convention as you've presented some important dependencies ( and I'm sure there's more ). Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

FoggyDay's answer is correct. Lots of libraries and tooling are dependent upon the get/set/is property naming convention.

However, Groovy, a scripting language built on the JVM, offers the some of the syntactic sugar that you're looking for:

```
class Person {
  String name
  int birthYear
}
```

Compiles into Java like this:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int birthYear;

  public String getName(){ return name; }
  public int getBirthYear(){ return birthYear; }
  public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
  public void setBirthYear(int birthYear){ this.birthYear = birthYear; }
}
```

See here for more details: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans

Answer (score 0):

For users of the popular annotations library **lombok**, this can be easily configured by setting the below property in the `lombok.config` file that is usually placed under src/main/java. It makes sure accessor methods are not prefixed with get, set or is.

```
lombok.accessors.fluent = true
```

The given class compiles into this. Note the return type of the setters that allow function chaining.

```
@Getter 
@Setter
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int birthYear;

    public String name() { return name; }
    public int birthYear() { return birthYear; }
    public Person name(String name) { this.name = name; return this; }
    public Person birthYear(int birthYear) { this.birthYear = birthYear; return this; }
}
```